# Nginx Flet deployment with assets setup

Tags: python, nginx, flet

I have a RPI as a webserver running Python apps with Channels and Celery without any major problems.

I followed a great Flet WeatherAPP tutorial from SmartGuruCool @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8heQa3Y6Mg&list=PLeVoANZdfMVS42-Ouq4DnL43_t75Qm2NR&index=15

I followed the Flet docs for self hosting @ https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/deploying-web-app/hosting-providers/self-hosting/

The APP works but without loading the assets images and fonts.

I will post my server configurations in case any one needs some help as it does work but with no static files working :-(

MY file structure is very simple:

```
            │   ├── assets
            │   ├── fonts
            │   │   ├── Comfortaa-Bold.ttf
            │   │   ├── Comfortaa-Light.ttf
            │   │   ├── Comfortaa-Medium.ttf
            │   ├── logo
            │   │   └── logo.svg
            │   └── weather_icons
            │       ├── day
            │       │   ├── 113.svg
            │       │   ├── 116.svg
            │       └── night
            │           ├── 392.svg
            │           └── 395.svg
            └── main.py




#My systemd service - /etc/systemd/system/flet_weather.service
[Unit]
Description=flet_weather Server
After=network.target

[Service]
User=rm
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/rm/www/flet/flet_weather
Environment="PATH=/home/rm/venvs/flet_weather/bin"
ExecStart=/home/rm/venvs/flet_weather/bin/python 
/home/rm/www/flet/flet_weather/main.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and my Nginx sites-available

```
#My Nginx config - /etc/nginx/sites-available/flet_weather
server {
listen 80;
listen 443;
server_name flet_weather.example.com www.flet_weather.example.com;
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }


location / {
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8503/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

location /ws {
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8503/ws;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
}
```

The APP Code:

```
    import requests

    language = 'pt'

    def get_weather_details(location):
      api_key = 'api_key_here'

      base_url = f'http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/'
      endpoint = 'current.json'

      url = f'{base_url}{endpoint}?key={api_key}&q={location}&lang={language}'

      response = requests.get(url)

      weather_dictionary = {}

      if response.status_code == 200:
        weather_data = response.json()
        
        weather_dictionary['Location'] = f'{weather_data["location"]["name"]}, {weather_data["location"]["country"]}'
        weather_dictionary['Temperature'] = f'{weather_data["current"]["temp_c"]}'
        weather_dictionary['Condition'] = f'{weather_data["current"]["condition"]["text"]}'
        weather_dictionary['Icon'] = f'{weather_data["current"]["condition"]["icon"]}'
        weather_dictionary['Humidity'] = f'{weather_data["current"]["humidity"]} %'
        weather_dictionary['WindSpeed'] = f'{weather_data["current"]["wind_kph"]} km/h'
        weather_dictionary['Pressure'] = f'{weather_data["current"]["pressure_mb"]} millibars'
        weather_dictionary['Precipitation'] = f'{weather_data["current"]["precip_mm"]} mm'
        weather_dictionary['Gust'] = f'{weather_data["current"]["gust_kph"]} km/h'
        weather_dictionary['UVIndex'] = f'{weather_data["current"]["uv"]}'

        # getting the icon path
        icon_location = weather_dictionary['Icon'].split('/')
        icon_location[-1] = icon_location[-1].replace('png','svg')
        icon_location = icon_location[-2] + '/' +icon_location[-1]

        # saving the icon path in weather dictionary
        weather_dictionary['IconLocation'] = icon_location

        weather_dictionary['Climate'] = f"{weather_data['current']['condition']['text']}"

        return weather_dictionary
      
      else:
        return f'error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}'



    def get_forecast_details(location):
      api_key = '6698de5404884127a0b171051241301'

      base_url = f'http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/'
      endpoint = 'forecast.json'

      url = f'{base_url}{endpoint}?key={api_key}&q={location}&lang={language}'

      response = requests.get(url)

      weather_dictionary = {}


      if response.status_code == 200:
        weather_data = response.json()    
        forecast_hourly_detail = list(weather_data["forecast"]["forecastday"][0]["hour"])
        
        for i in forecast_hourly_detail:
          # Fetching hourly time     
          timestamp = i["time"]
          time = timestamp.split(" ")
          time = time[-1]

          # fetching the icon path
          icon = i['condition']['icon']
          icon_location = icon.split("/")
          icon_location[-1] = icon_location[-1].replace("png", "svg")
          icon_location = icon_location[-2] + '/' + icon_location[-1]

          # getting daily temperature in celsius
          temp_c = int(round(float(i["temp_c"])))
          temp_c = str(temp_c) + "°C"

          weather_dictionary[time] = {'logo':icon_location, 'temp_c':temp_c}
        
        return weather_dictionary
      else:
        return f'error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}'
      
    from flet import *
    import os
    import datetime
    import locale
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')

    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    formatted_date = current_date.strftime('%A, %B, %d')

    weather_data = get_weather_details('Sao Paulo')
    forecast_data = get_forecast_details('São Paulo')

    # set Flet path to an empty string to serve at the root URL (e.g., https://lizards.ai/)
    # or a folder/path to serve beneath the root (e.g., https://lizards.ai/ui/path
    DEFAULT_FLET_PATH = ''  # or 'ui/path'
    DEFAULT_FLET_PORT = 8503

    def main(page: Page):
      page.title='Previsão do Tempo'
      page.padding=0
      page.vertical_alignment='center'
      page.horizontal_alignment='center'
      page.theme=Theme(color_scheme_seed='green')

      page.fonts={
        'Comfortaa-Bold': 'fonts/Comfortaa-Bold.ttf',
        'Comfortaa-Light': 'fonts/Comfortaa-Light.ttf',
        'Comfortaa-Medium': 'fonts/Comfortaa-Medium.ttf',
        'Comfortaa-Regular': 'fonts/Comfortaa-Regular.ttf',
        'Comfortaa-SemiBold': 'fonts/Comfortaa-SemiBold.ttf',
      }

      # generating multiple items for containing hourly weather data
      def hourly_items_report():
        items = []
        for k,v in forecast_data.items():
          time = k
          logo = v['logo']
          temp = v['temp_c']

          hourly_icon = Image(height=50)
          hourly_time = Text(font_family='Comfortaa-Medium',style='titleMedium',color=colors.WHITE)
          hourly_temp = Text(font_family='Comfortaa-Medium',style='titleLarge',color=colors.WHITE)
          hourly_container = Column([
            hourly_icon,
            hourly_time,
            hourly_temp
          ],horizontal_alignment='center')
          
          # setting the values of hourly container
          hourly_icon.src = f"weather_icons/{logo}"
          hourly_temp.value = temp
          hourly_time.value = time

          items.append(
            Container(
              content=hourly_container,
              alignment=alignment.center,
              width=150,
              height=150,
              border_radius=border_radius.all(5),
          )
          )
        return items

      splash_screen_data = Column(
        [
          Text(
            value='Previsão do Tempo', font_family='Comfortaa-Bold', style='displaySmall', text_align='center'),
          Container(height=20),
          Image(src='logo/logo.svg', width=200),
          IconButton(icon=icons.ARROW_FORWARD_IOS,
                    icon_color=colors.WHITE,
                    icon_size=30,
                    on_click=lambda _: page.go("/homepage"),
          ),
          Container(height=20),
          Container(
            content=Text(
              value='Dev: RMCode',
              font_family='Comfortaa-Medium',
              style='labelLarge',),
              bgcolor='#019877',
              padding=10,
              border_radius=10,
          )
        ],
        horizontal_alignment='center',
        alignment='center',
      )
      splash_screen=Container(    
        content=splash_screen_data,
        gradient=LinearGradient(
          begin=alignment.top_center,
          end=alignment.bottom_center,
          colors=["#001a31", "#019877"]
        ),
        width=500,
        height=800,
        border_radius=5,
        padding=20,
      )

      # homepage contents
      homepage_data = Column([
        Container(height=5),
        Text(value=formatted_date,font_family="Comfortaa-Light",color=colors.WHITE,style='titleLarge'),
        Text(value=weather_data['Location'],font_family="Comfortaa-Bold",style='titleLarge',color=colors.WHITE),
        Container(height=10),
        Image(src=f"weather_icons/{weather_data['IconLocation']}",width=150),
        Container(height=10),
        Text(value=f"{weather_data['Climate']}",font_family="Comfortaa-Light",style='titleLarge',color=colors.WHITE),
        Text(value=f"{int(round(float(weather_data['Temperature'])))}°",font_family='Comfortaa-Light',style='displayLarge',color=colors.WHITE,size=100),
        Container(height=15),
        Divider(color=colors.WHITE),
        Row(spacing=10,controls=hourly_items_report(),scroll='auto'),
        Row([
            IconButton(
                icon=icons.ARROW_BACK_IOS,
                icon_color=colors.WHITE,
                icon_size=30,
                on_click=lambda _: page.go("/")
            ),
            IconButton(
                icon=icons.ARROW_FORWARD_IOS,
                icon_color=colors.WHITE,
                icon_size=30,
                on_click=lambda _: page.go("/weatherdetails")
            ),
        ],alignment=MainAxisAlignment.SPACE_BETWEEN),
        
        ],horizontal_alignment='center')

      homepage_body=Container(
        content=homepage_data,
        gradient=LinearGradient(
          begin=alignment.top_center,
          end=alignment.bottom_center,
          colors=["#001a31", "#019877"],
        ),
          width=500,
          height=800,
          border_radius=5,
          padding=20,
      )

      # weather details content
      weather_indepth_data = Column([
        Container(height=5),
        Text(value=formatted_date,font_family="Comfortaa-Light",color=colors.WHITE,style='titleLarge'),
        Text(value=weather_data['Location'],font_family="Comfortaa-Bold",style='titleLarge',color=colors.WHITE),
        Container(height=15),
        Divider(color=colors.WHITE),
        Container(height=5),
        Row([
          Text(value='Humidade',font_family="Comfortaa-Light",style='titleLarge',color=colors.WHITE),
          Text(value=weather_data['Humidity'],font_family="Comfortaa-Light",style='titleLarge',color=colors.WHITE),
        ],alignment=MainAxisAlignment.SPACE_BETWEEN),
        Container(height=5),
        Row([
          Text(value='Vento',font_family="Comfortaa-Light",style='titleLarge',color=colors.WHITE),
          Text(value=weather_data['WindSpeed'],font_family="Comfortaa-Light",style='titleLarge',color=colors.WHITE),
        ],alignment=MainAxisAlignment.SPACE_BETWEEN),
        Container(height=5),
        Row([
          Text(value='Pressão',font_family="Comfortaa-Light",style='titleLarge',color=colors.WHITE),
          Text(value=weather_data['Pressure'],font_family="Comfortaa-Light",style='titleLarge',color=colors.WHITE),
        ],alignment=MainAxisAlignment.SPACE_BETWEEN),
        Container(height=5),
        Row([
          Text(value='Precipitação',font_family="Comfortaa-Light",style='titleLarge',color=colors.WHITE),
          Text(value=weather_data['Precipitation'],font_family="Comfortaa-Light",style='titleLarge',color=colors.WHITE),
        ],alignment=MainAxisAlignment.SPACE_BETWEEN),
        Container(height=5),
        Row([
          Text(value='Rajadas',font_family="Comfortaa-Light",style='titleLarge',color=colors.WHITE),
          Text(value=weather_data['Gust'],font_family="Comfortaa-Light",style='titleLarge',color=colors.WHITE),
        ],alignment=MainAxisAlignment.SPACE_BETWEEN),
        Container(height=5),
        Row([
          Text(value='UV',font_family="Comfortaa-Light",style='titleLarge',color=colors.WHITE),
          Text(value=weather_data['UVIndex'],font_family="Comfortaa-Light",style='titleLarge',color=colors.WHITE),
        ],alignment=MainAxisAlignment.SPACE_BETWEEN),
        Container(height=5),
        Divider(color=colors.WHITE),
        Container(height=15),
        Row(spacing=10,controls=hourly_items_report(),scroll='auto'),
        IconButton(
          icon=icons.ARROW_BACK_IOS,
          icon_color=colors.WHITE,
          icon_size=30,
          on_click=lambda _: page.go("/homepage")
        )
        ],horizontal_alignment='center',alignment='center')

        # weather details container
      weather_indepth_body = Container(
        content=weather_indepth_data,
        gradient=LinearGradient(
          begin=alignment.top_center,
          end=alignment.bottom_center,
          colors=['#001a31','#019877']
        ),
        width=500,
        height=800,
        border_radius=5,
        padding=20
      )
      
      
      def route_change(route):
        page.views.clear()
        page.views.append(
          View(
            "/",
            [
              splash_screen,
            ],
            scroll='auto',
            vertical_alignment='center',
            horizontal_alignment='center',
            padding=0,
          )
        )
        if page.route=="/homepage":
          page.views.append(
            View(
              "/homepage",
                [
                  homepage_body,
                ],
                scroll='auto',
                vertical_alignment='center',
                horizontal_alignment='center',            
                padding=0,
            )
          )
        if page.route=="/weatherdetails":
          page.views.append(
            View(
              "/weatherdetails",
                [
                  weather_indepth_body,
                ],
                scroll='auto',
                vertical_alignment='center',
                horizontal_alignment='center',
                padding=0,
            )
          )
      def view_pop(view):
        page.views.pop()
        top_view=page.views[-1]
        page.go(top_view.route)

      page.on_route_change=route_change
      page.on_view_pop=view_pop
      page.go(page.route)
      

    #app(target=main, view=AppView.FLET_APP_WEB, assets_dir='assets')
    if __name__ == "__main__":
      flet_path = os.getenv("FLET_PATH", DEFAULT_FLET_PATH)
      flet_port = int(os.getenv("FLET_PORT", DEFAULT_FLET_PORT))
      app(name=flet_path, target=main, view=None, port=flet_port, assets_dir='assets')
```

I tryied to add assets location to nginx sites-available like we do with python but did not work.
If somebody knows on how to make this works I will appreciate!

Thank you very much!

Comment: have you found a solution to this? I am encountering an identical problem... my NGINX reports a lot of 404s for assets, but loads the "index.html" flet creates...

Comment: Not yeat. But to be honest I stoped working with Flet and started Kivy. But when I have time I will try id out again! Sorry